# SQLite query with 3 entities in Hibernate 4 (nested join?)

Tags: database, hibernate, sqlite

I have the following tables in my database (**SQLite**):

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE feedback(
  product INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  score NUMERIC,
  textnote VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY(product) REFERENCES product(id)
)

CREATE TABLE product_detail (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    product INTEGER, 
    description TEXT, 
    url VARCHAR, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(product) REFERENCES product (id), 
)
```

So `feedback` is in a one-to-one relationship with `product` and `product_detail` is in a many-to-one relationship with `product`.

I am trying to write a SQLite **query** for **Hibernate 4** that will give me all the attributes from the 3 tables in one single table. All I came with by far is this:

```
String hql = "SELECT p.id, p.name, d.id, d.description, d.url " +
            "FROM ProductDetail d INNER JOIN d.product AS p";
```

I'm correctly obtaining the values I want from `product` and `product_detail`. How can I add to the query also the information in `feedback`? I know all products have at least one product detail, but I can't say the same about feedback: most of the products don't have a feedback. I think I should use a `LEFT JOIN` but I can't figure out how...
Note that as I'm using Hibernate I have all classes relative to the tables in my application (`Feedback`, `ProductDetail` and `Product`).

Answer (score 1):

You must also join `feedback`:

```
SELECT 
  p.id, p.name,
  f.score, f.textxnote, 
  d.id, d.description, d.url
FROM product p 
INNER JOIN feedback f ON f.product = p.id
INNER JOIN ProductDetail d ON d.product = p.id
```

You may change to `LEFT` the joins if there is a case that a product does not have a row in either of the tables `feedback` and `ProductDetail`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I posed the wrong question thou as the query I need is actually for Hibernate (indeed `ProductDetail` is actually a java class). I'll edit the original post!